# Improving performance of Eliminate tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, large-datasets, slivers

My data is very large (polygon feature class with 884187 features), thats why Python geoprocessing tools (which use geoprocesses like Intersect, Buffer etc.) don't work due to performance issues.

So my idea was to use the "Eliminate" tool in ArcGIS Pro to reduce the amount of sliver polygons. Problem is now, that this tool is also not working because the data is too large (it always stucks while "Reading feature ..."). I know that e.g. Intersect uses tiled geoprocessing automatically. Is there a way to do this manually (like a tool that splits the data into smaller parts), or is there a better way to remove sliver polygons, than "Eliminate"?

My data is a landuse map with many single part polygons:
[image]

**Technical Data:**

- PC: 64bit Windows 7, 8gb ram, 2,8GHz intel i5
- Hard Drive(on which data is safed): HGST Travelstar Z5K500 HTS545032A7E380,   320 GB, 2.5", SATA 3Gb/s - 5400 rpm - Buffer: 8 MB, Main Partition
- Software: ArcGIS Pro 2.1.0
- Data Source: Type: Shapefile, Projection (ETRS 1989 LAEA), Resolution (minY: -9.526.700m maxY: 15.968.500m minX: -8.462.600m maxX: 17.068.600m)

Comment: I regularly use datasets with 1, 5, 10, and 20 million rows, in both file geodatabase and PostgreSQL, and my processing operations usually finish in minutes, including an Intersect of 900k polygons through a 22m row fishnet. You need to drop back a bit and describe your system configuration, data organization, and filesystem metrics, because I expect this is more of a data organization issue than a software capability one.

Comment: You don't actually say what your data is! Is is it massively multi-part, such as a land cover map or thousands of building foot prints. An image would be helpful, simply edit your question.

Comment: "GDB" is not specific enough, since that could refer to personal, file, or enterprise geodatabase ( in which case we need the RDBMS). We also need details down to the access speed of the disk drives and how they are partitioned. And all of the information needs to be *in the question body*.

Comment: @Vince  Thanks for the advise, I edited the question

Comment: If you have an Advance license, then consider using the [Dice tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dice.htm) first then try your elimination step.

Comment: @Hornbydd I considered this already, but it changes the geometry of my polygons, doesnt it? I would prefer not to change/simplify it, because need the exact geometry for calculating landscape metrics with my data.

Comment: The 5400 RPM disk is your bottleneck. Get an SSD and try again.